# Why do I have to uninstall WebDav?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2, webdav

WebDav is preventing my clients from utilizing the common HTTP methods PUT and DELETE Microsoft recommends in their Repository design pattern:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

This tutorial is great other than the fact that it's completely incompatible with IIS due to IIS blocking PUT and DELETE methods, did I miss something from the tutorial?? Is Microsoft beginning to recommend APACHE or NGINX instead of IIS now?

The only option I'm left with now is uninstalling WebDav completely, so what's the point of WebDav other than acting like a digital appendix waiting to be removed?

And no I've tried doing everything to my Web.config and I've still had no luck with that:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

So my question is, is WebDav just about as useful as a hole in a bridge?

Comment: Is your question _"What is WebDAV"_, or just a rant? Do you understand how IIS modules and their configuration work?

Comment: @CodeCaster My question is are there any draw backs to removing this module that's installed by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS provides one implementation of Webdav, but there are many more. If you build your own REST api you are effectively building your own webdav implementation - you might just want to add PROPFIND support to make it complete.

I'm the author of a [webdav server framework for java](http://milton.io), and there are usually several companies at any one time implementing webdav in their server applications with webdav.

So your question is really: Is the IIS Webdav implementation useful? The answer is only very rarely. There just arent that many use cases for editing physical files in IIS over the internet.

The other question is "is the webdav protocol useful?", and the answer to that is a resounding YES, especially when you consider that iCloud is built on webdav for syncing files, calendars and contacts.

Answer (score 2):

> are there any draw backs to removing [WebDAV, which is] installed by default?

No. If you don't use it, you won't miss it.

WebDAV is a protocol that allows for file exchange between clients and HTTP servers that support it.